# Update "autofocus" attribute via interaction on template level in angular

Tags: html, angular

Having a problem regarding the `autofocus` attribute in cooperation with Angular. In detail I have a `<form>` with an `<input type="text">` on top which is initially focussed by a condition.

```
<input [attr.autofocus]="selection===-1"
       [(ngModel)]="myForm.firstInpElem" 
       name="firstInpElem" 
       placeholder="firstInpElem">
```

This is working as expected (Chrome).

Then the form continuous with a selection between two options controlled by an `<input type="radio">`.

Once a selection is made an according  element is shown and then should get the `autofocus`.

But that is not happening and I don't understand the reason for it.

Prepared a [stackblitz with a working example](https://angular-shift-autofocus.stackblitz.io/) but mainly below is the markup which won't work as expected

```
<h1>Forms example</h1>

<form>

  <pre>Condition to focus "firstInpElem" is {{selection===1|json}}</pre>

  <p>This input element is autofocussed on page load</p>

  <p>
    <input [attr.autofocus]="selection===-1"
           [(ngModel)]="myForm.firstInpElem" 
           name="firstInpElem" 
           placeholder="firstInpElem">
  </p>

  <p>
    Provide one of both information:<br>

    <label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="selection" 
             name="radioInpElem"
             type="radio"
             [value]="1"> 
             Option 1
    </label>
    <br>

    <label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="selection" 
             name="radioInpElem"
             type="radio"
             [value]="2">
             Option 2
    </label>

  </p>

  <pre>Condition to focus "secondInpElem" is {{selection===1|json}}</pre>
  <pre>Condition to focus "thirdInpElem" is {{selection===2|json}}</pre>
  <p>


  <input *ngIf="selection===1"
        [attr.autofocus]="selection===1"
        [(ngModel)]="myForm.secondInpElem"
        name="secondInpElem"
        placeholder="secondInpElem">



  <input *ngIf="selection===2"
          [attr.autofocus]="selection===2"
          [(ngModel)]="myForm.thirdInpElem"
          name="thirdInpElem"
          placeholder="thirdInpElem">
  </p>
</form>


<pre>{{myForm|json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check in the development tools (F12 tools), you will see that the new input control actually gets the `autofocus` attribute, but it does not get the focus. That is because `autofocus` sets the focus on an element [when the page loads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/autofocus). In your case, the page is already loaded when the new element becomes visible.

What you can do instead is to set the focus programmatically on the new input element. In order to do that, you can define a common template reference variable for the two input elements having an `ngIf` condition:

```
<input #inputElement *ngIf="selection === 1"
      [(ngModel)]="myForm.secondInpElem"
      name="secondInpElem"
      placeholder="secondInpElem">

<input #inputElement *ngIf="selection === 2"
        [(ngModel)]="myForm.thirdInpElem"
        name="thirdInpElem"
        placeholder="thirdInpElem">
```

and monitor the presence of these elements with `ViewChildren` and the `QueryList.changes` event. Each time one of the input element becomes visible, you set the focus on it:

```
@ViewChildren("inputElement") inputElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.inputElements.changes.subscribe(() => {
    this.inputElements.last.nativeElement.focus();
  });
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shift-autofocus-chhyjv) for a demo.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan this is working perfectly. Didn't knew that autofocus is applied only when page loads

Answer (score 0):

Another option is hide the inputs (not use *ngIf else display.style) and reference variables
see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbc4pp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
    <label>
      <input [ngModel]="selection" (change)="change(second,1)" 
             name="radioInpElem"
             type="radio"
             [value]="1"> 
             Option 1
    </label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input [ngModel]="selection" (change)="change(third,2)"
             name="radioInpElem"
             type="radio"
             [value]="2">
             Option 2
    </label>

  <input #second [style.display]="selection===1?'inherit':'none'"
        [(ngModel)]="myForm.secondInpElem"
        name="secondInpElem"
        placeholder="secondInpElem">

  <input #third [style.display]="selection===2?'inherit':'none'"
          [(ngModel)]="myForm.thirdInpElem"
          name="thirdInpElem"
          placeholder="thirdInpElem">
```

Your function change like

```
  change(element:any,index:number)
  {
  this.selection=index;
  setTimeout(()=>{element.focus()},0);
  }
```