# Is it possible to use the same template reference variable for different elements?

Tags: angular

Consider this case, where the two different divs never exist at the same time:

```
<!-- Mutually exclusive containers -->

<ng-container *ngIf="predicate">
  <div #myRef>
    ...
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!predicate">
  <div #myRef>
    ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

And, in my component:

```
@ViewChild('myRef', {read: ElementRef}) private myRef: ElementRef;

// do something with myRef...
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can even use the same variable for elements that are present at the same time, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52155735/1009922).

Comment: Sure I tried it. I was wondering whether it was advised against. Sorry, I should have specified.

Comment: another use case would be to have *n* no. of elements with same template ref variable and access them in your component class like this `@ViewChildren('myRef', {read: ElementRef}) allMyRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have.
Even if you have 2 same template ref in your template, if you try to fetch using @ViewChild then you will get the first ref.

```
<ng-container >
  <div #myRef>
  <p> this is the first content, </p>
    </div>
</ng-container >


<ng-container >
    <div #myRef>

  <p> this is  the Seoncd content, </p>
    </div>
</ng-container >
```

[image]

```
 @ViewChild('myRef') myRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.myRef.nativeElement);
  }
```